# Error: 'ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch' when refreshing a report in Crystal Reports

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

Using
Crystal Reports 2013
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

```
Failed to retrieve data from the database.
Details: HY000: [Oracle][Ora]ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch
```

I have no comments (multi-line or single line), so https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/2322011 doesn't apply.

The query works fine in DbVisualizer.

I'm trying to combine two reports.  Records from the summary report should be in the group footer of the detail report.  (Yes, my first thought was to use a subreport and call it a day.  When I determined the report would take all week to run, I decided to have the database server do all of the work.)

My query is 384 lines long, uses 16 parameters, and has no comments.  It is a join of two main queries.  I have tried using subqueries and common table expressions.  As expected, same results both ways.  All of the parameters used in the query are in the Parameter List in the Modify Command window in Crystal Reports.  I have looked through every parameter definition in the Parameter List and they all look good.

When I have seen this error message before, I was able to delete comments and move forward.  This is different.

Any idea what Crystal Reports is doing here?

Comment: Is there an ampersand character in your query somewhere - perhaps in a string literal?

Comment: Also note https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284833/warning-ocifetch-function-ocifetch-ora-24374-define-not-done-before-fetch

Comment: No ampersands anywhere in the query.  And this is Crystal Reports, not php, so I don't understand how your second comment applies.

Comment: Didn't know how things might be getting invoked. If it doesn't apply, so much the better. :-)

Comment: I recreated the report from a far earlier point and it's working now.  One possibility is that one of the parameters was defined wrong.  ({?HideThis} rather than {?ShowThis} -- I recently changed a bunch of reports.)  The parameter definition looked good in the Parameter List, but maybe it didn't match the exact parameter name in the SQL.  The error message really doesn't help.  You'd think that if Crystal can map the parameter values to the parameters in the SQL, it could identify when there is a mismatch instead of expecting the database server to do all of the work.